# Apache NiFi Hive Processors with Hive 1.1 (CDH 5.7.1)

Tags: hive, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager, apache-nifi

I work with Cloudera Manager CDH 5.7.1, which supports only Hive 1.1.0.
NiFi 1.0.0-BETA uses Hive 1.2.1.

When I try to use SelectHiveQL processor, I get the following error: `Required field 'client_protocol' is unset!`, which means that there's a **version mismatch** between Hive client and server.

Any suggestions to solve this problem?

I thought about building NiFi with `hive-jdbc` dependency version `1.1.0` instead of the default `1.2.1`, but I hope there's a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

Since NiFi is an Apache project, it builds with Apache JARs (such as Hive and Hadoop). However there are vendor-specific profiles and build properties you can use to build NiFi for a particular Hadoop distribution.

For example you could try the following to build a NiFi distro for CDH 5.7.1:

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests -Pcloudera -Dhadoop.version=2.6.0-cdh5.7.1 -Dhive.version=1.1.0-cdh5.7.1 -Dhbase.version=1.2.0-cdh5.7.1
```

The Hive processors use Hadoop libraries provided by the NiFi Hadoop Libraries NAR, and other NARs (like the Hadoop/HDFS processors) use this same libraries NAR, so the best approach is to build the whole thing. Otherwise you can try to replace just the Hadoop/Hive/HBase-related NARs and see if that works.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I encountered an error when I tried to build it. `Compilation failure: error: package org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.filters does not exist`. Probably too old version. Any ideas?

Comment: Package does not exist, you can try to get it working removing it and make the body  of function which use the missing package empty (  NO BODY ).  I did this and compile but still the protocol version mismatches.

Answer (score 2):

Because NiFi expects the newer version of Hive, it is necessary to remove the unsupported newer features (such as HiveStreaming and ORC support), support the older version of Thrift, and build against the Cloudera-specific libraries.

I have created a branch of the current NiFi-1.1.x release with the necessary changes to get the PutHiveQL and SelectHiveQL processors to work, which you could build as below:

```
git clone https://github.com/Chaffelson/nifi.git
git checkout nifi-1.1.x-cdhHiveBundle
mvn -T C2.0 clean install -Pcloudera -Dhive.version=1.1.0-cdh5.10.0 -Dhive.hadoop.version=2.6.0-cdh5.10.0 -Dhadoop.version=2.6.0-cdh5.10.0 -DskipTests
```

I have posted a more complete coverage of this on the Hortonworks Community forum: https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/93771/connecting-nifi-to-cdh-hive.html